# Heroku + Rack-Rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, url-rewriting, rack

Still can't get this working...Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2 on Heroku's Cedar Stack.

Trying to use https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite to make http://domain 301 redirect to http://www.domain to no luck (app works, but no redirects happen at all).

/config/initializers/rack_rewrite.rb (MyAppName is actually the correct name, domain.com is actual domain):

```
MyAppName::Application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
    r301 %r{.*}, 'http://www.domain.com$&', :if => Proc.new {|rack_env|
    rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.domain.com'
    }
end
```

Added to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-rewrite'
```

Did "gem install rack-rewrite", "bundle install".

No luck.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

**I have figured out PART of the problem. Since I'm just trying to serve "index.html" and it's "/style" folder, it appears that having "index.html" in "/public" overrides the rack-rewrite. If I remove "index.html", the rewrites work...but now I don't know where to put the files, or set up the routes.rb to direct to the index.html page by default...any help?**

Comment: It really is strange. I've checked the snippet against half a dozen of our Heroku/Cedar/Rails app which uses this code and it is exactly correct. Most odd!

Comment: Am I missing something, like a "require rack-rewrite" in some file?

Comment: nope, nothing like that. It would be loaded automatically being as it's in the gemfile.

Comment: Try logging, log the env stuff, and the rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] env['REQUEST_URI'] and the result of your check. I think on heroku it's just puts to log.

Comment: I'm pretty new to ruby/rails, honestly I'll admit I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: just to show that my sample does actually work on heroku - visit http://stark-beach-5145.herokuapp.com and you'll be immediately redirected since the domain doesn't match kyan.com - github project is https://github.com/johnbeynon/rackrewritetest - entirely vanilla Rails 3.1 with rackrewrite and the initializer.

Comment: If I load MyAppName.herokuapp.com it doesn't do anything...other than load what should be there

Comment: I think I've found a lead! Since I'm serving a single page (index.html) with a /style folder for it's CSS...if I remove the index.html page, all of a sudden the Rewrite works.

Comment: If you have an index.html in public then that is what is being served and not your Rails application - just like when you forget to delete the template one when you run `rails new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.domain.com'
```

to

```
rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] == 'domain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe env["SERVER_NAME"] could be an internal dns in this case like 'app7009.intra.foo'. I do some stuff with domains in middleware in heroku: I look at both env['REQUEST_URI'] and env['PATH_INFO'], mainly because the POW-server I use locally doesn't set REQUEST_URI. It's a bit different how different servers populate the env hash, I wish this URL request part would be more standard with something like rack.

```
env['REQUEST_URI'] !~ /www.domain.com/
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting for me to change something?

Comment: I think you should look in 'REQUEST_URI' instead of 'SERVER_NAME' for this rewrite, this is because SERVER_NAME might not actually be www.foobar.com but rather the internal name of the server behind the proxy. It's a proxied setup at heroku.

Comment: So I should change to rack_env['REQUEST_URI'] != 'www.domain.com'
instead of rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.domain.com'

Comment: No, you should not use !=, request URI is the full URI. Use a regexp, like in my example.

Comment: so `rack_env['REQUEST_URI'] !~ /www.domain.com/` = no go, as was `env['REQUEST_URI'] !~ /www.domain.com/` in case that's what you meant

Comment: This did not help me... in fact it gave my application errors and wouldn't even load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this so I have no logical explanation as to why it works but it worked for me when I put the codes in `config/application.rb` instead of a new file `/config/initializers/rack_rewrite.rb`.