# Redirecting naked URL to www DNS issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I'm on heroku and I'm trying to get `http://domain.com/*` to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/*`. Using `rack-rewrite`, I got `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/*` to successfully redirect to `http://www.domain.com/*`. I can't however get `http://domain.com/*` to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/*`.

Looking at a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395184/rails-proper-setup-with-dns-rack-rewrite-etc-for-heroku), it seems I'm supposed to set my A record to point to myapp.herokuapp.com. I could set my CNAME (www) to myapp.herokuapp.com, but when I tried to do so with my A record I got this error:

```
INVALID_IP: 'myapp.herokuapp.com' is not valid IP for A record. (host name: @)
```

I've tried it with `myapp.herokuapp.com.` as well but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried setting @ to other record types but none gives me the `http://domain.com/*` I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Ok so setting @ to a CNAME completely fixed the problem. I'm not sure why everything I've read referenced A record though.

Comment: Yeah a CNAME is essentially another domain or subdomain to connect through, an A record is an IP Address.

Comment: Note that there are some downsides to doing that.  In particular, availability.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords